# Visual Studio 2013 Documentation link

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Is it possible to create shortcut to Visual Studio 2013 Help Viewer? It is possible to start if from Visual Studio IDE, Help menu. I want to run it, for example, from a desktop shortcut.

In previous Visual Studio versions there are shortcuts in Windows start menu, for example: "Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Documentation". 2013 doesn't have such shortcut.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Help Viewer is located at %ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Help Viewer\v2.1\HlpView.exe. Just create a shortcut to it. HlpView.exe requires some parameters,

> Usage: HlpViewer.exe /catalogName  [/options]

it gives a sample:

> HlpViewer.exe /catalogName VisualStudio12 /locale en-us

Personally, I don't use Help Viewer and it doesn't have any content on my computer. Just try it on your machine.

Comment: VS2015: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Help Viewer\v2.2\HlpViewer.exe" /catalogName VisualStudio14